# Как написать кастомный цикл?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Как все знают, существуют циклы while, do while и for в JavaScript.
Сделать кастомные циклы можно с помощью других циклов. Например так можно получить аналог цикла while с помощью for:

```js
for (; true;) {
  // code
}
```

Мы получаем бесконечный цикл. Вопрос таков: возможно ли сделать кастомный цикл, но без встроенных в язык циклов? Искал ответ и тут и в англоязычном коллективе, но ответа и близко не нашёл.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751207/how-can-i-use-goto-in-javascript

Comment: Первый вариант goto( ссылка выше) Еще вариант - рекурсия)))

Comment: только вот интересно, на кой тебе это?))

Comment: Цыклы мне казались какими то странными. Только в них я видел, чтоб аргументы писались с " ; ". Стало интересно а как это реализовать, После нескольких минут раздумий я пришол к такому странному попросу)

Comment: Без рекурсии не обойтись, разумееться, А goto в языке javascript как таковой, нету. Есть ссылки на функции.

Comment: Можно и без рекурсии обойтись - закольцевать колбек функциии;)

Comment: А есть что-то типа forEach?

Comment: @Flippy так есть именно foreach =)

Comment: forEach не работает для объектов. К тому же, сама цель была создать всё без уже существующих методов и конструкций.

Answer (score 4):

Язык javascript не позволяет программисту создавать собственные синтаксические конструкции, все возможные конструкции должны явно поддерживаться парсером языка. В общем-то, это относится к любому языку.

Тем не менее, существуют языки, в которых циклы не являются особой частью синтаксиса и могут быть реализованы библиотечно. В частности, сюда относятся Lisp-подобные языки.

Comment: Полезная информация, но вот только вопрос в том, как реализовать это использую всё, что даёт язык. К счастью, я уже это почти реализовал. Осталось немного доработать и избавиться от багов.

Answer (score 0):

Процессор выполняет последовательность инструкций. Цикл в ней образуется инструкцией условного или безусловного перехода, после выполнения которой снова выполняется та же последовательность (тело цикла).

Во многих языках можно явно использовать инструкцию безусловного перехода `goto`, но js такую инструкцию не предлагает и поддерживает только `break` (в том числе с меткой) для выхода из цикла или блока и `continue` (тоже можно с меткой) для продолжения цикла. Для создания цикла этих инструкций недостаточно.

Почти в любом языке цикл можно заменить рекурсией. Это возможно и в js, но оптимизация хвостовой рекурсии (которая должна быть по стандарту ES6) почти не поддерживается, так что такие фокусы могут привести к переполнению стека.

Цикл может быть скрыт в неком методе, например, многие методы массива внутри содержат цикл, т. е. при их вызове в коде цикла нет, но фактически цикл есть.

Регулярные выражения по сути являются полноценными программами и могут содержать циклы. Например `/^((.*)\n)*$/` по сути создаёт 2 вложенных цикла.

Ещё если есть вызывающая сторона, которая будет выполнять итерирование, то вызываемый код можно превратить в конечный автомат, соответственно, вместо любого числа вложенных циклов можно сделать код линейной структуры, выполняющийся в рамках одного цикла на вызывающей стороне. В простейшем случае с генератором код будет развёрнут самим движком, но при желании можно сделать что-то аналогичное самостоятельно. Ну и в принципе имея один бесконечный цикл с меткой снаружи, можно использовать `switch` для выполнения различных линейно расположенных кусков кода.

PS: А `for (; true;)` можно записать в виде просто `for (;;)`.